# Download the file using angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a rest end point .

When i am hitting it directly then i getting file (A.xlsx)

but when using angular i am doing then , aPBF[content-Type].xml... as response i am getting .

```
$http.get('/download').then(function(response){
console.log(response);
var data = new Blob([response],{type:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
FileSaver.saveAs(data,"A.xlsx");
});
```

After googling i got file Saver . After using it am able to download it but it is getting corrupted .

Comment: how  corrupted it is , provide the data inside .

Comment: It has content, directly i am able to download , but using angular i am not able to